# Trouble posting variable from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am trying to send a JS a variable to a php file. It is not happening. And there are many questions answered out there on similar situation. I probably am making some similar mistake. Though, I am not able make out what it is.

The Codes are as follows;

main.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var socialurl= "<?php echo $url;?>";</script>
```

JS

```
jQuery(function(){
    alert('socialurl');
    $("#smshare").click(function(){
       $("#smp").slideToggle("fast");
       $.post("social-media-share.php", {socialurl: socialurl });
       $("#smp").load("social-media-share.php");
     });
});
```

social-media-share.php;

```
<?php 
   $socialurl=$_POST['socialurl']
   echo $socialurl."<br>"; 
   include('conn.php');
   $socialurl = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['socialurl']));
?>

<a href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php echo $socialurl;?>" data-text="<?php echo $socialurl;?>" data-href="" class="wa_btn wa_btn_s"><img src='images/share.png' width="30" height="30" alt='WhatsApp Share'></a>
```

The file social-media-share.php is called into the main.php with JS. Prior to which the JS variable socialurl is defined in the main.php

The variable value pops up in alert in the JS but it is not getting posted to social-media-share.php

I am sure I must be making some silly mistake. But for the life of me am not able to find out what.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the **`$url`** you echo? It's not shown anywhere else.

Comment: I have defined the $url earlier and it is passed on to the javascript too and it shows in the alert as well. Only issue is with the $.post not working

Comment: In your JS snippet you are alerting the string `'socialurl'`rather than the variable `socialurl`. Are you sure the JS variable is initialised correctly?

Comment: Also, did you check with the browser developer panel what got sent in the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you're posting to the page, but then loading it again via a GET request and so you're not loading the results of the post request itself.So unless the GET on social-media-share.php is displaying a database result I'm not sure you're actually loading what you want.

```
jQuery(function(){
    alert('socialurl');
    $("#smshare").click(function(){
       $("#smp").slideToggle("fast");
       $.post("social-media-share.php", {socialurl: socialurl });
       $("#smp").load("social-media-share.php");
     });
});
```

This bottom line is doing the wrong thing. $("#smp").load("social-media-share.php");

you actually want a callback function in you .post that loads the response from that

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post( "social-media-share.php", {socialurl: socialurl })
  .done(function( data ) {
//you might need to do some other stuff to data here
    $("#smp").html(data);
  });
```

Alternatively you might have an error in your social-media-share.php script so you could try doing a `var_dump($_POST);` to see what variables are actually being posted

Comment: The load function simply displays a whatsapp share link which will have the url in its message text. The reason I have a separate file is that I have all other social media share buttons also displayed along with it. And I don't want it to slow up the page by loading along with the main page.  Btw, I don't understand what you meant by loading via 'GET' request. What am I loading via 'GET' request here ? And why is a call back mandatory ?  I simply want the 'socialurl' variable to be captured  in the social-media-share.php file. Thats all. Rest I can process there itself.

Comment: $("#smp").load("social-media-share.php"); with this line you are loading the whole php page again. That is the GET request. When you POST to the page, unless you are saving that url anywhere and then loading it from a db when you call social-media-share.php it will be lost. If you do the post and then use the callback, you will have access to the data in the page at that time. The callback means you will load the data at the point of the POST request. Whereas currently you are posting to the page and getting a response but ignoring it. Then you are loading the page again without any post data

Comment: If you just load the social-media-share.php page in a browser do you see any errors

Comment: But the problem here is, the variable is not getting posted to social-media-share.php at all ! Because, shouldn't the $_POST  contain something ? It shows array(0) { }. Rest everything has to happen after the post value is received, isn't it ? When that in itself shows as 'undefined index' when #smp is called. And #smp is populated with the share links and so data cannot be appended there

Comment: yes it should show something. Have you tried the callback method and amending your file to just do "print_r($_POST)" or are you accessing the file and seeing that? POST requests dont hang around. Sorry I'm not sure what your level of PHP is so not sure how new this is to you.

Try my callback method and see what that shows

Comment: Have tried var_dump and print_r. No result. Now trying to figure out what to do in call back. Am not too good with Js. Will update soon.

Comment: Yep. That Worked, @TommyBs. I removed the load function and stuck to #smp.html(data). Thanks a ton !

Comment: Glad you got it working. Do you understand why. When you made a post request you weren't actually capturing the results of that AJAX request (which is what the callback has). You were then calling the same page via the .load function which was a GET request that had no notion of the previous post as it was another request

Comment: That made a lot of sense ! Thanks again for the explanation. Really appreciate it.